# Changing TCP/IP RFC Destination IP Address in SAP

Tags: saprfc, idoc

A couple months ago a new RFC destination was configured in SAP to allow IDOCs to be sent to another program, ADAPTRIS.

We have since changed the server that hosts ADAPTRIS and the IDOCs no longer send successfully.

Checking SWU2 shows the following error

> Error when opening an RFC connection

How do I change the IP Address of the RFC destination in SAP?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question also depends on whether the data is sent to ADAPTRIS via HTTP or via RFC. For the HTTP case, SunCatcher already gave the solution below. However, if ADAPTRIS is an RFC program, the configuration may need to be changed differently (and perhaps not even on SAP side in SM59, but on ADAPTRIS side).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SM59 tcode](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/da/11df3a9b10355ae10000000a11405a/content.htm) for editing RFC-connections.

[image]

Depending on connection type its destination can be changed, for example, like this:

[image]